# Convert Multidimensional List to Blob

Tags: list, salesforce, type-conversion, blob, apex

I have a list that I'd like to convert to a Blob. I first tried converting the list to a long string, like so:

```
List<Contact_Deals__c> result = ...SOQL Query...    

String strSobjects = null;
for(integer i=0;i<result.size();i++){
   If(strSobjects == null){
      strSobjects = String.valueOf(result2[i]);
    }
    Else{
        strSobjects = strSobjects  + ','+String.valueOf(result[i]);
    }
 }
```

and then converted the string into a blob, like so:

```
Document resultD = new Document(); 
resultD.Name = 'ResultCSV'; 
Blob myBlob = Blob.valueof(strSobjects);
resultD.body = myBlob;
```

This worked fine for a 2 dimensional List, but now my list has gotten deep. Real deep. Should I try writing a recursive call to convert it all into one large string (it's JSON format, so it can be parsed later) or is there a better way to convert this list to a blob?

EDIT: This will have to work in SF apex, which is a bit more limited. It seems that the only way to write to a blob is via a string (is this obvious? Blobs are new to me): https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_blob.htm

Thanks all!

Zac

Comment: Are all the things in your list Serializable? If so, have you tried serialzing the entire list? OutputStream out = blob.setBinaryStream(0) then serialize the whole list to that?

Comment: The data should be serializable. It can be converted to text (are there things that can be converted to text that aren't serializable?). I tried looking up how to use an OutputStream with no luck. Maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Also, it seems that salesforce apex doesn't support OutputStream...